# dojox gfx make a node moveable after getting sgv from json

Tags: javascript, json, svg, dojo, dojox.gfx

I have a surface with some shapes. I use

```
dojox.gfx.utils.toJson(surface)
```

to generate a json from it, and then

```
dojox.gfx.utils.fromJson(surface, json)
```

to get the data and append it to the surface.
The problem comes when I create a moveable node. After saving it to json and then appending it to the surface, the node is no longer moveable. I found no way of making the node moveable again. Is there a way to do this?
I want to be able to save and load svg data in my page and after load, move the elements around. Using dojo seemed easy enough before i stumbled on this problem. If I can't do this easy, is there a better library I can use, to achieve my goal?

Edit: here is the actual code: http://pastebin.com/2qLCTw8B

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem.

First of all, when you require a dojo module it is good to assign it to a variable, which i didn't know. This way when assigning the on module, you can use the on function, used to add event listener, anywhere in the code. From there it is easy to create a moveable node, when you click on it.

It seemed though that this is a useless operation, as you could just iterate over the surface - children array, and make every node moveable.

Here is the improved code: http://pastebin.com/wAvSnZpN

The code needed, if you decide to use events anyway:

```
function HandleMouseDown(e) {
    var foo = new dojox.gfx.Moveable(e.gfxTarget);
}

on(surface, 'mousedown', HandleMouseDown);
```